# Accordion animations using scss

Tags: css, angular, animation, sass

I'm currently using Angular 8, would like to know how to do the following animation from the fave website https://discover.myfave.com/sg

[image]

Here's my code

**steps.html**

```
<div class="step-flow">
  <div class="step">
    <div class="title">Title 1</div>
      <div class="step-progress step-progress-1"></div>
      <div class="description">
         this is the first section
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
     <div class="title">Title 2</div>
       <div class="step-progress step-progress-2"></div>
       <div class="description">
          this is the second section
       </div>
     </div>
  <div class="step">
     <div class="step-progress step-progress-3"></div>
        <div class="title">Title 3</div>
        <div class="description">
          this is the third section
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**steps.css**

```
.step-flow {
        width: 45%;

        .step {
          position: relative;
          border-left: 4px solid $color-black;
          margin-bottom: 2rem;
          padding-left: 2rem;

          .step-progress {
            position: absolute;
            left: -4px;
            top: 0;
            right: auto;
            bottom: 0;
            background: $color-yellow;
            width: 4px;
          }

          .step-progress-1 {
            animation: fillin 2s infinite;
          }
          .step-progress-2 {
            animation: fillin 2s infinite 2s;
          }
          .step-progress-3 {
            animation: fillin 2s infinite 4s;
          }

          .title {
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            font-weight: 900;
            margin-top: 1rem;
            margin-bottom: 0;
          }

          .description {
            margin-top: 0.5rem;
            margin-bottom: 2rem;
          }
        }
      }

@keyframes fillin {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

The animation just flows at the same time. How do I make it flow step by step? Do I use step() in css? Would like to achieve the same effect as the fave website, thank you :)

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Chances are, that's a slider/gallery and it simply triggers animation on the currently active item.

Comment: is there a way to play the animations one after another without using a slider?